# How to prevent two vertically aligned divs from moving while resizing window

Tags: html, css, layout, resize, window

I have a couple of vertically aligned divs which i want to be fixed when window is resized horizontally.

Here is the CSS. Any idea what is missing here? :

```
.wrapper {
     display: block;
     float: right;
     width: 350px;
     margin-right: 5px;
 }

.upper-div {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right:5px;
    display: block;
    top: 7px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: right;
}

.lower-div {
    line-height: 11px;
    font-size: 11px;
    bottom: 7px;
    height: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    text-align: right;
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "you want them to be fixed"?

Comment: When the window resizes to a smaller width, the wrapper div moves on top of the div to its right. I want it to stay at its own position irrespective of window resizing

Comment: is this what you have? 
http://codepen.io/funkysoul/pen/zNByGJ

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i have

Comment: can you draw what you are trying to achieve? I don't see the issue you're having.

Comment: Could you also post the html or post the entire code so that I can help?

Comment: @funkysoul  It's an internal company code so I will prefer not to paste a whole lot of it... I am new to StackOverflow so I can't see the create room next to your Username as well. Is there a way I can IM you ? On Stackoverflow or any other chat application ?